# Magento CLI install: in table "core_resource" column "data_version" remains null, why?

Tags: php, magento, installation, command-line-interface

i try to install Magento 1.5.1 via cli.

As far as i can see all database tables are created with relevant content, but in table `core_resource` i can see the `data_version` comming from sql dir (mysql4-data-upgrade... files) is missing. At all rows in `core_resource` the column `data_version` is null. Why?

CLI is called according to the instructions here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/command_line_installation_wizard

A `Mage::app()->cleanCache();` after installation do not help.

I can fix this by do a login to the backend SYSTEM / CACHE MANAGEMENT and refreshing of CacheType=CONFIGURATION. But how to do that via cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer never calles the applyAllDataUpdates() to make the installation complete. Install.php trusts that the magento downloader was used before, which does a call to applyAllDataUpdates().

But in my case i did not use the magento downloader, because i installed a magento instance from a local git repository (for buildserver, dev machine, etc.) via my own ant script. I gussed that the cli install is independend from the downloader (by design) - but here a "hidden" dependency is discovered. Running cli installer alone, setup the extensions without upgrading "data_version".

Normally you can trust in the first http call to the magento frontend / backend, which calls the applyAllDUpdates() and applyAllDataUpdates() if there is a error with the config (in cache), but in this case the cache was created successfull (extension config) by the installer - so no applyAllDataUpdates() is triggered.

I am running unit tests, integration tests and function tests (in that chain) after a build of magento (without using the downloader). I get strange behaviours if "data_version" is not poluted. My solution is to add:

```
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates();
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates();
```

to the bootstrap of my unit tests.

Comment: Hmm, which magento version do you use? In my CE 1.6 in `\app\code\core\Mage\Install\Model\Installer\Console.php` I see `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates();` on the line #381.